# I updated a library in middle of my project and now <switch> function is not working

Tags: reactjs, routes, switch-statement

I updated a few library in middle of my project(i cant remember which ones exactly) and now  function is not working it displays "Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'". when i try routing without  url changes but component isnt displayed. I tried inpirting  from 'rect-router' too dosrnt work.

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Home from './components/Pages/Home';
import Intro from './components/Pages/Intro';
import LogIn from './components/Pages/LogIn';
import SignUp from './components/Pages/SignUp';
import Recomendations from './components/Pages/Recomendations';
import Reviewed from './components/Pages/Reviewed';
import AboutUs from './components/Pages/AboutUs';
import Bookmarks from './components/Pages/Bookmarks';
import Error from './components/Pages/Error';
import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

function App() {
  
    return (
      <>
        <Router>
          //routing through pages
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/'  component={Intro} />
            <Route path='/home'  component={Home} />
            <Route path='/error'  component={Error} />
            <Route path='/bookmarks'  component={Bookmarks} />
            <Route path='/reviewed'  component={Reviewed} />
            <Route path='/aboutus'  component={AboutUs} />
            <Route path='/recomendations'  component={Recomendations} />
            <Route path='/signup'  component={SignUp} />
            <Route path='/login'  component={LogIn} />
            <Route path='/intro'  component={Intro} />
            
          </Switch>
        </Router>  
        
      
      </>
    );
   
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took me a real long time to fix this.
I deleted node modules and installed all dependencies again with npm install. this woked for me